# Odoo 10 - QWeb report widget contact - Missing state_id

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, qweb

I have the following field using widget contact.

```
<div t-field="o.partner_id" t-options="{&quot;widget&quot;: &quot;contact&quot;, &quot;fields&quot;: [&quot;address&quot;, &quot;name&quot;], &quot;no_marker&quot;: True}"/>
```

This does not display the `state_id`, how can I include it?

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit `base.contact` template to add `state_id` field.

```
<template id="contact" inherit_id="base.contact">
    <xpath expr="//address/div[2]/div[2]" position="after">
        <div t-if="object.state_id and 'state_id' in fields" 
           class='css_editable_mode_hidden'>
            <div itemprop="state_id" t-esc="object.state_id.name" 
                 style="margin-bottom:4px;font-size:14px;"/>
        </div>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

Then to use it in a QWEB report just specify `state_id` field in `fields` attribute.

```
<address t-field="o.partner_id" t-field-options="{&quot;widget&quot;: &quot;contact&quot;, &quot;fields&quot;: [&quot;address&quot;, &quot;name&quot;, &quot;state_id&quot;], &quot;no_marker&quot;: true}"/>
```

*I used `div[2]/div[2]` to add state_id just after country.*

Comment: did this help you

Answer (score 0):

I finally found it was a configuration setup. Odoo by default does not include state_id for most countries. This is configured in `settings->localization->country`

Answer (score -1):

You can pass in the option inside t-field-options param as below.

```
<div t-field="o.partner_id" 
t-fields-options='{"widgets": "contact", "fields": ["address", "name", "phone", "email"], "no_marker": true }'
/>
```

**Field "address" contains whole address of partner including state_id**.

Comment: Hello M.E., for that you have to call 

<t t-call="report.external_layout">